# Bottom space constraint proportional to height of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, constraints

I have a view at the bottom of my view controller which has the following constraints:

- align centre horizontally
- fixed aspect ratio (1:1)
- proportional width to width of view controller
- bottom space of -50

How do I make the bottom space constraint proportional to the height of the view using Auto Layout? Meaning that if the height of the view is 250, the bottom space will be -50, but if the height is 300, the bottom space will be -60, and so on (the proportion is fixed at 0.2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the multiplier value. You want the bottom of your view to be 0.8 times the bottom of the superview.

[image]

Comment: My interface builder does not show the bottom layout guide. Any way I can enable this? Also, how does this take the height into account?